# Clion GCC complier Mac

Tags: c++, g++, homebrew, clion

I'm trying to change my Clion(ver 2020.3) complier from the default clang to g++. I have already installed g++9 with homebrew but I'm having trouble to change it in Clion. Most of the respond I found is for windows not Mac. So can anyone teach me how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I accidentally set the directory to gcc instead of g++, because after I corrected it, the compiler works.